# Update modifications in Sharepoint lists, views, webparts, automate scripts and power app forms to production

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

I am working on a power apps project where I had to

- add some columns to a sharepoint list
- change the dateformat of sharepoint
- add a automate script and modify an existing automate script
- modify a couple of views and webparts
- and also modify a power apps form

What would be the best way to export and import all these changes to production?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work only with sharepoint, to have everything in the same place, you could make a powerapp and embed it to the site.
To search details on how to do the things you wrote, you can find a lot of tutorial on youtube and google.